# copying files from windows cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to make a backup of the files in a corrupted MySQL database before doing a clean install from a different backup file.  I am on a windows 7 machine.  Someone suggested the following, but the `mv` command does not work on windows:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
```

So instead, I am trying to use `robocopy`, but I am getting a range of different error messages with each attempt.  Here is a screen shot of some of the error messages for my various attempts:

[image]

Here is a link to the complete suggested code in a related posting, if it helps anyone suggest the correct syntax:  [Click Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65728/forcing-innodb-recovery-of-a-corrupted-database/65736?noredirect=1#comment118435_65736)

I tried `xcopy` but am getting the following error result:

[image]

Then I tried `move` but got the following results, despite trying a few different ways of doing the slashes:

[image]

I added a `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\bkup` folder to my hard drive and tried the following:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Googling "mv windows" would have been much quicker than asking here.

Comment: @Biffen Of course I already did that before posting.  And got the `robocopy` approach which I tried above.  And all the syntax errors which I illustrate in the print screen.  Would you address the syntax errors and show the correct syntax please?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `move /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old`? I don't see the need for robocopy.

Comment: @Biffen On my machine, the paths are different.  Please look at my print screen.  On my machine, there are spaces in the path.  The errors may be due to the spaces in the path.

Comment: @Biffen I tried `move` but it was giving syntax errors due to the spaces.  Please consider such things before reflexively downvoting.

Comment: `move "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\" data\mysql.old` (Looks like you tried to quote the whole command (but failed).)

Comment: @Biffen I tried your code verbatim but am getting an error stating `the system cannot find the file specified`.  The source url is a directory of all files in the MySQL database.  The second url is just a place to put the copy.  There is currently no `mysql.old` file.

Comment: I haven't got a Windows machine to test it, but I've used similar commands before. Did you check for typos? You didn't put the whole command in quotes, right?

Comment: ...also, use the whole paths. (Learn the difference between relative and absolute paths.) If your current directory is `C:` and you run `move ... data\mysql.old` then your destination will be `C:\data\mysql.old`, and if `C:\data` does not exist then you're likely to get errors about non-existing stuff.

Comment: @Biffen Thank you.  I posted another screen shot at the end of my original posting above to show how I implemented your suggestions. `mysql.old` does not exist yet, but the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\` folder does exist and does contain a collection of files that together comprise the database.

Comment: **Does `C:\data` exist and is it a directory?** 'Cause that's where you're trying to move your other directory.

Comment: @Biffen I created a `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\bkup` folder on my machine and tried to copy to that directory, but got the errors that I show in yet another printscreen which I just now added to the end of my original posting above.  Thank you for your patience.  But it still is not working.

Comment: Please only use images when absolutely necessary (when there is no other alternative to demonstrate your issue). It makes the question difficult to read from a mobile device, uses bandwidth and data that is still expensive for some people who use this site, and the images are frequently blocked by corporate proxy servers which makes the question meaningless. All of the above information could have been provided in block-quoted sections, using the command window's ability to mark, copy, and paste content, without a single image being needed.

Comment: Robocopy isn't the best way to move files, but if you really want to, the quoting is simple, e.g.: `robocopy "c:\working\z for luck\x and y" "c:\working\test this" /move` though you might also need /e if there's more than one directory level involved.

Comment: Regarding the `move` command, the source path can't have a trailing backslash (or forward slash).  The correct syntax is, e.g., `move "c:\working\z for luck" "c:\working\zz"`

Answer (score 2):

why don't use this syntax ? :

```
xcopy /s SOURCEDIR DESTDIR
eg: xcopy /s C:\Users\Iman\Desktop\k C:\Users\Iman\Desktop\kk
```

Comment: Thank you.  How do I address spaces in the path, as shown in my print screen above?

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  I posted a second screen shot at the end of my original posting above showing the result of trying xcopy.  Can you suggest how to fix it so that it works?

Comment: @CodeMed : try use DIR command , when you go to the first & second path directory and then use DIR , does it show the list of files in folders?

Comment: i also found this links , but cannot test on my computer , you'd better test it :) 
wish it helps ;) 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192808

Comment: Thank you.  dir results in a list of files for each of the directories. But the link you sent had a warning that it does not apply to windows 7.  I do not have a `"Prevent MS-DOS-based programs from detecting Windows" check box` in my `cmd.exe` properties.  Sorry for the delay.  I have been doing a lot of backup stuff and uninstalling to make room for this big database operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach, since the paths seem to be crossing you up:

```
 MD C:\BackupDir 

 Subst G: c:\BackupDir

 Cd C:\MypathtoMysql

 G: (Switch to G drive)

 Xcopy C:*.* /s /e
```

That way you're in the directory you want to copy so no need to specify it, and you're copying to a local location rather than a path location.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to give an answer.  I got tired of all the errors, so I just used the windows gui to drag and drop the contents of the `data` directory into the `bkup` directory.  This means I do not have a MySQL.old file.  I just have all the original files in a new location.  Do you think my manual approach gave different results than your approach?

Comment: @CodeMed - It shouldn't, unless you've got some weird permissions on hidden files. Drag and drop would have been my first guess, I figured there was some reason you wanted it done at the CLI level.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've done this to prove what I tried to convey in the comments:

1. Created a directory called `C:\ProgramData\directory 1\sub-directory a`, and two files in it:

   ```
   C:\>dir "C:\ProgramData\directory 1\sub-directory a"
    Volume in drive C has no label.
    Volume Serial Number is 303C-DB3D

    Directory of C:\ProgramData\directory 1\sub-directory a

   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          .
   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          ..
   24/05/2014  22:35                13 file 1
   24/05/2014  22:35                13 file 2
                  2 File(s)             26 bytes
                  2 Dir(s)  1,076,169,957,376 bytes free
   ```
2. Created a directory `C:\ProgramData\directory 2`:

   ```
   C:\>dir "C:\ProgramData\directory 2"
    Volume in drive C has no label.
    Volume Serial Number is 303C-DB3D

    Directory of C:\ProgramData\directory 2

   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          .
   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          ..
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes
                  2 Dir(s)  1,076,169,957,376 bytes free
   ```
3. Used `move` to move `sub-directory a` to `C:\ProgramData\directory 2` like so:

   ```
   C:\>move "C:\ProgramData\directory 1\sub-directory a" "C:\ProgramData\directory 2\sub-directory a"
           1 dir(s) moved.
   ```
4. Confirmed that the directory and its files are where they should:

   ```
   C:\>dir "C:\ProgramData\directory 2\sub-directory a"
    Volume in drive C has no label.
    Volume Serial Number is 303C-DB3D

    Directory of C:\ProgramData\directory 2\sub-directory a

   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          .
   24/05/2014  22:35    <DIR>          ..
   24/05/2014  22:35                13 file 1
   24/05/2014  22:35                13 file 2
                  2 File(s)             26 bytes
                  2 Dir(s)  1,076,169,957,376 bytes free
   ```

In conclusion:

- `move` can be said to be a renaming operation: The first argument, the source, is the path of the file *right now*, the second argument, the destination, is *what you want it to be*.
- The parent directory of the destination should exist. E.g. if I move to `C:\ProgramData\directory 2\sub-directory a` there should already be a directory `C:\ProgramData\directory 2`.
- Arguments that contain a space need to be quoted, like the directory arguments to `move`. Each argument should be quoted on its own.
- Use relative paths *when you're sure about what they should be*, otherwise use absolute paths.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason why you want this done via command line? Why not use a file-diff tool such as [**Beyond Compare**](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php)? This tool gives you a visual overview of file differences, but can be used to copy files to another folder for backup as well. Full binary comparison of files in different folders is possible too. [**See a screenshot**](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=FolderCompare). **There is a command line version included**.

Perhaps this topic from SuperUser can help: https://superuser.com/questions/748069/how-do-i-compare-two-folders-recursively-and-generate-a-list-of-files-and-folder - look down the list of answers and there will be an entry on RoboCopy and its use for a somewhat similar purpose.

Comment: The question is not about comparing directories, it's about moving a directory, a task for which the command line is a very good choice, among other things because it doesn't require the installation of any applications.

Comment: That tool is capable of moving any file / folder anywhere with binary comparison to verify the backup integrity - no complications to look out for. Also, the link to SuperUser is showing you a post with a working command line for RoboCopy for a similar scenario - the tool you asked for help with.